# Statemachine to behaviour tree?

Tags: libgdx, mathematics, state

#### Background

I was able to convert simple statemachines like this...

[image: Simple Statemachine]

Into a BT looking like this ([Notation describtion](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai/wiki/Behavior-Trees#sequence))...

```java
root
  sequence  #After another
    playAnimation name:idle
    sequence
      walks? # Breaks current sequence if false
      playAnimation name:walk
    sequence
      runs?
      playAnimation name:run
```

#### Goal

But how do we convert more complex multi-layered animation states into a behaviour tree ? How would such a BT look like ? The difficult parts here are transistions between the different states, something i couldnt solve in an BT.
[image: More complex example]

#### Question

Is it possible to convert every statemachine into a behaviour tree ?
What does the theory says and how does it look like in practice ?